# Streaming ChatGPT's results with Flask and LangChain

Tags: python, flask, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

Basically I want to achieve this with Flask and LangChain: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8uwwLNxqis.

I'm building a Q&A Flask app that uses LangChain in the backend, but I'm having trouble to stream the response from ChatGPT. My chain looks like this:

```
chain = VectorDBQA.from_chain_type(llm=ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", streaming=True, chain_type="stuff", vectorstore=docsearch)
...
result = chain({"query": query})
output = result['result']
```

Jinja simply prints the `{{ output }}`, and it works fine, but the result doesn't appear in the website until the entire response is finished. I want to stream the result as it's being generated by ChatGPT.

I've tried using `stream_template`, but it doesn't work (it doesn't stream the result, it just prints the full response at once, although I could be doing something wrong).

---

I finally solved it:

https://github.com/DanteNoguez/FlaskGPT

Comment: What was it that made it work? I can get it to stream in the console, but not through the responses.

Comment: Same for me, @SunwooYang

Comment: @devZ I ended up switching to FastAPI with websockets for this one

Answer (score 2):

In order to make it clearer that this question has an answer and to avoid broken links in the future (common StackOverflow problem when someone leaves only a link), Dante (OP) solved it here:

https://github.com/DanteNoguez/FlaskGPT

```
def gen_prompt(docs, query) -> str:
    return f"""To answer the question please only use the Context given, nothing else. Do not make up answer, simply say 'I don't know' if you are not sure.
Question: {query}
Context: {[doc.page_content for doc in docs]}
Answer:
"""

def prompt(query):
     docs = docsearch.similarity_search(query, k=4)
     prompt = gen_prompt(docs, query)
     return prompt


def stream(input_text):
     completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=[
            {"role": "system", "content": "You're an assistant."},
            {"role": "user", "content": f"{prompt(input_text)}"},
        ], stream=True, max_tokens=500, temperature=0)
     for line in completion:
        if 'content' in line['choices'][0]['delta']:
            yield line['choices'][0]['delta']['content']

@app.route('/completion', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def completion_api():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.form
        input_text = data['input_text']
        return Response(stream(input_text), mimetype='text/event-stream')
    else:
        return Response(None, mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

Answer (score 2):

as of now, chains in Langchain do not stream. `streaming=True` is misleading, this kwarg make openai servers stream the response to your llm, but the chain does not accept the response as streaming. Even though there is `chain.stream` method, it does not stream. I can prove it:

```
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import LLMChain

# streaming=True controls how openai api responds to langchain
llm=ChatOpenAI(openai_api_key="your api key",streaming=True)
prompt=ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([("human","{content}")])

chain=LLMChain(llm=llm,prompt=prompt)

response=chain.stream(input={"content":"tell me a joke"})

# this returns generator
print(response)

for res in response:
    print(res)
```

this is the results of 2 print statements. second print statement should be streaming but it actually sends the full complete message:

[image]

The streamed response should look like this

[image]